# Cocoa UI IBAction call seems to corrupt NSTimer

Tags: macos, user-interface, cocoa, ibaction

I have a function:

```
    NSTimer *learnUSBTimer=nil;

    - (void)showUSBWindow:(id)sender {
       [self updateDeviceButton:@"Cancel"];
       [self hideDeviceClearButton:TRUE];
       [selectedDeviceField setStringValue:@"Insert the USB device..."];
       learnUSBMode=1;
       if(learnUSBTimer)
          {
          if([learnUSBTimer isValid])[learnUSBTimer invalidate];
          learnUSBTimer=nil;
          }
    }
```

And it seems my message sent to the timer object is being sent to the UI object:

```
2018-02-19 14:02:34.649581-0500 TokenLock[4068:819373] -[NSBox isValid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000016bc40
2018-02-19 14:02:34.649691-0500 TokenLock[4068:819373] [General] -[NSBox isValid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000016bc40
2018-02-19 14:02:34.651799-0500 TokenLock[4068:819373] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4f33833b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff7607c942 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4f3cf5e4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4f2aff03 ___forwarding___ + 1443
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4f2af8d8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   TokenLock                           0x0000000100014cdc -[AppController showUSBWindow:] + 252
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff4d02375a -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 312
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff4cac9933 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff4cac985b __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 136
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff4cac9761 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 183
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff4cb0aa18 -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 97
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff4cac7fca -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2438
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff4cb0a75f -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 777
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff4cac6a64 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 965
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff4d1c2959 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5891
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff4d1bf5b0 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2359
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff4d1be85c -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 497
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff4d01f617 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 307
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff4c880d9d -[NSApplication run] + 812
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff4c84ff1a NSApplicationMain + 804
    20  TokenLock                           0x0000000100001ea1 main + 97
    21  TokenLock                           0x0000000100001e34 start + 52
)
```

I dont understand how my NSTimer is being somehow assigned to the UI Box being clicked to execute the function?

Comment: Your error is telling you that `learnUSBTimer` is a `NSBox`, not a `NSTimer` Show us where you set this variable. The problem isn’t in the code here, but elsewhere, where you set this variable.

Comment: When you get an “unrecognized selector sent to instance” error, step 1 is **always** to run with zombies enabled.  Have you tried that? (If you don’t know how to run with zombies enabled, just use your favorite search engine and you’ll find step-by step instructions.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there will be some memory management issue in your code. And the objects are not properly allocated/ deallocated or not initialised deinitialised properly.
So to solve this issue just run your code by enabling zombies into your project target settings.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this timer fires once. I was not setting it to nil in that code and so it became essentially an orphan because the system released the actual timer object after.

Setting it to nil on firing fixes the issue.